# Process Affinity using OpenMP proc_bind

Tags: c, process, parallel-processing, openmp, affinity

I did observe that, using

> ```
> #pragma omp parallel proc_bind(master)
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> #pragma omp parallel proc_bind(close)
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> #pragma omp parallel proc_bind(spread)
> ```

dint produce significant improvement when executing a CPU bound C program using OpenMP.
Expecting to know if its normal behaviour.

Comment: With no idea about your program, nor about your hardware, any 'answer' would be a waste of time; our time writing, your time reading.  More details required.

Comment: Why do you expect _significant improvement_?

Comment: Well, execution using 16 threads took longer time than 2 or 4 threads, but upon analysis, as the number of threads increased, memory bound operations also increase. To reduce it, I checked with proc_bind(), so that there may be less cache miss' . But by using #pragma omp parallel proc_bind(spread|master|close) there were no significant difference.